# Отправить Post-запрос в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, post

Всем доброго. Вот запрос:

```
r = requests.post(url + "create_user/", 
                  json=[{"name":"Lilit","login":"........","password":"......"}])
```

Но у меня надо вводить ключ:значение. В Postman это вот так
[image: Скрин]
Как добавить к запросу эти ключ:значение?

Comment: На первой же странице документации написано ведь https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

Comment: @andreymal прошу прощения. Замотался погд вечер)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может кому поможет)

```
headers = {'X-TMP-TOKEN': 'sometoken'}
r = requests.post(url + "create_user/", headers=headers, json={"name":.......
```